# Rails looking for Nonexistent ID column in schema_migrations table during initial migrartion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rails-postgresql

Running migration on a fresh db results in the following error.

```
>> rake db:drop; rake db:create:all; rake db:migrate
                                                                                           1 activity-image-additions-!?
==  CreateSomething: migrating ================================================
-- create_table(:somethings)
   -> 0.0042s
==  CreateSomething: migrated (0.0043s) =======================================

rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: ...O "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id"
                                                                   ^
: INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" ("version") VALUES ($1) RETURNING "id
```

The SQL query generated should not include `RETURNING "id"` since the schema_migrations table does not have ids.

If I attempt to migrate the database after the failure, it succeeds:

```
>> rake db:migrate

==  CreateSomething: migrating ================================================
-- create_table(:somethings)
   -> 0.0041s
==  CreateSomething: migrated (0.0042s) =======================================
```

I'm currently running PostgreSQL 9.2.4, Rails 4.0.0, pg gem 0.16.0 on OS X 10.8.

The sole migration:

```
class CreateSomething < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :somethings do |t|
      t.integer :x
      t.integer :y
    end
  end
end
```

Note: I have tried this migration in other Rails projects, and it works. Something else is amiss, but I'm not sure where to start.

Stack trace is available [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YKf3YXim).

Comment: I just ran the same exact migration locally with SQLite and Postgres and had no problems.

Comment: Exactly. I did the same in a different Rails project with no issues. Something else is amiss... but I'm not sure what.

Comment: The `schema_migrations` table is used by the migrations system to keep track of which migrations have been run, it should have a single `version varchar(255) not null` column. Any chance of seeing a stack trace from that exception?

Comment: Here's the [stack trace](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=YKf3YXim).

Comment: I'm not sure why that `RETURNING "id"` bit is being appended...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you setup a fresh database, you should not run `rake db:migrate`. Instead, you should use `rake db:schema:load`.

The migration system is designed to update a schema. On a fresh install is faster and more convenient to load the latest schema immediately.

Comment: Looks like I had mixed up `create` with `setup`. Also, is this a DB specific issue? I don't see this error when using sqlite.

Answer (score 5):

In my case this problem was caused by the **attribute_normalizer** gem. (See [issue 42](https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer/issues/42))
It only happened with a completely empty database after the very first migration.

Using the 1.2 prerelease fixed the problem.